# Why is Windows 10 no longer detecting Macs?

Tags: windows-10, home-networking

I have file sharing turned on for two Macs -- connected via BT Homehub. Windows 10 usually discovers them automatically and they are normally listed in the Network window. For some reason, without knowingly changing any settings, Windows 10 is no longer discovering both Macs. It does however detect other devices in the house.

I have done the following to try to remedy the problem:

- Restarted all machines.
- Turned the router on and off again.
- Ensured that Windows file sharing is turned on on the Macs.
- Ensured network discovery is enabled on the Windows PC.

Nothing I've tried has worked. As I said, it was working fine before. I transferred some files to the Mac from the PC this morning. I left the house with the Mac -- left the PC on -- but when I returned, the PC could no longer see the Mac.

From here, I'm lost. What else could I try to fix this?

**Update**

I had given up on this in the hope it would resolve itself on its own. However, I have just discovered one of the Quick Access icons (left sidebar in Explorer) points to the Mac's desktop. Clicking this icon, I am prompted with the login window and I am then able to access the Mac's files.

So the problem isn't that Windows can't see the Macs, they're just not showing up in the Network window.

** Update **

This resolved itself automatically. Not sure why.

Comment: Can you connect the PC **directly** to the mac? (You can use an Ethernet cable)

Comment: I tried to connect the two via Ethernet cable but had no luck. Internet sharing via Ethernet was turned on.

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but have you rebooted your computer since this has happened?

Comment: Can it _reach_ the Macs? (As in, by specifying their IP address manually?)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Windows so I'm not sure how to do that at the moment. However, the Mac's IP address is listed in the output of `arp -a`.

Comment: You can get the IP address of your Windows by typing `ipconfig` in **Command Prompt**. Check if it is similar (or the same) as the Mac's IP.

Comment: I've checked and the machines have different IP addresses.